# fill dates for date range in DATE row

Tags: php, mysql

Two questions:

1. When i click 'Go' , how to fill DATE row all dates of the date range in the two text box
2. How to keep textbox for all IN and OUT row

When I click 'submit', the in out textbox must saved to the DB:

```
    <?php
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['uname']) {
header("Location:login.php");
}
?>
<html><head><title>Attendance sheet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="att_style.css" type="text/css" >
<script src="datetimepicker.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function IsNumber(strFieldValue, size, strAlert)
{
for ( var i=0; i < size; i++)
{     
if(strFieldValue.charAt(i)!="" )
{       
if( strFieldValue.charAt(i) < "0" || strFieldValue.charAt(i) > "9")
{
if(strAlert != "")alert(strAlert)
return false;
}
}
}
return true;
}

function IsValidTime(timeStr) {
var timePat = /^(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})(:(\d{2}))?(\s?(AM|am|PM|pm))?$/;

var matchArray = timeStr.match(timePat);
if (matchArray == null) {
alert("Time is not in a valid format.");
return false;
}
hour = matchArray[1];
minute = matchArray[2];
second = matchArray[4];
ampm = matchArray[6];

if (second=="") { second = null; }
if (ampm=="") { ampm = null }

if (hour < 0  || hour > 23) {
alert("Hour must be between 1 and 12. (or 0 and 23 for military time)");
return false;
}
if (hour <= 12 && ampm == null) {
if (confirm("Please indicate which time format you are using.  OK = Standard Time, CANCEL = Military Time"))        {
alert("You must specify AM or PM.");
return false;
}
}
if  (hour > 12 && ampm != null) {
alert("You can't specify AM or PM for military time.");
return false;
}
if (minute<0 || minute > 59) {
alert ("Minute must be between 0 and 59.");
return false;
}
if (second != null && (second < 0 || second > 59)) {
alert ("Second must be between 0 and 59.");
return false;
}
return false;
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="timeform" method="post" action="" >

<label for="range_start">Start range:</label> <input name="from" id="frm_date" type="text" >

<a href="javascript:NewCal('frm_date','ddmmyyyy')"><img src="cal.gif" alt="pick a date"></a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<label for="range_end">End range:</label> <input name="to" id="dpk" type="text" >

<a href="javascript:NewCal('dpk','ddmmyyyy')"><img src="cal.gif" alt="pick a date"></a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input name="date_but" type="submit" value="Go">
<a style="float:right" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
<br/><br/>
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['date_but'])) {
$fromDate = $_REQUEST['from'];
$toDate = $_REQUEST['to'];

$dateMonthYearArr = array();
$fromDateTS = strtotime($fromDate);
$toDateTS = strtotime($toDate);

for ($currentDateTS = $fromDateTS; $currentDateTS <= $toDateTS; $currentDateTS += (60 * 60 * 24)) {

$currentDateStr = date("d-M-Y",$currentDateTS);
$dateMonthYearArr[] = $currentDateStr;

}

echo "No of days: " . count($dateMonthYearArr);
?>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center">
<tr>
<th scope="row">DATE</th>
<div class="dat_row">
<td><?php print_r($dateMonthYearArr[0]); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $dateMonthYearArr[1]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $dateMonthYearArr[2]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $dateMonthYearArr[3]; ?></td>        
</div>

</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">IN</th>
<td><input name="time" type="text" ></td>
<td><input name="r2_in" type="text" ></td>
<td><input name="r2_in" type="text" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">OUT</th>
<td><input name="time" type="text"></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Leave</th>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table><br/><br/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" onClick="IsValidTime(document.timeform.time.value);" value="Submit">
<?php

} ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  SO is not meant to be a "write my code for me" site - if that's what you are looking for, you should probably hire an expert to do it for you. If you have a *specific* technical question arising of your working on the issue, feel free to edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
  function GetDays($sStartDate, $sEndDate){  
  // Firstly, format the provided dates.  
  // This function works best with YYYY-MM-DD  
  // but other date formats will work thanks  
  // to strtotime().  
  $sStartDate = gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime($sStartDate));  
  $sEndDate = gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime($sEndDate));  

  // Start the variable off with the start date  
  $aDays[] = $sStartDate;  

  // Set a 'temp' variable, sCurrentDate, with  
  // the start date - before beginning the loop  
  $sCurrentDate = $sStartDate;  

  // While the current date is less than the end date  
  while($sCurrentDate < $sEndDate){  
    // Add a day to the current date  
    $sCurrentDate = gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($sCurrentDate)));  

    // Add this new day to the aDays array  
    $aDays[] = $sCurrentDate;  
  }  

  // Once the loop has finished, return the  
  // array of days.  
  return $aDays;  
}
```